# Separating different Views in Android Studio using RecyclerView and CardView

Tags: android, android-layout, firebase, android-recyclerview, android-cardview

I am using **FirebaseRecyclerViewAdapter** with **CardView** in my application and want to load **video on one card** and **images on another**, but I dont know how to separate them. Everytime I add a videoView in CardView layout it gets added on the top of ImageView in same card and also **gets repeated** in all the RecyclerView. Its like same thing is coming again and again with number of posts I have. I want that VideoView should play video on different post and ImageView shows images on different, I have searched many options but did not find anything useful, please help.

> I am using Android Studio

**CardView xml file:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/CardView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    card_view:cardCornerRadius="10dp">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

       <com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerView
            android:id="@+id/youtube"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="200dp"/>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/po_image"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/ti_cardView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/de_cardView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:paddingRight="10dp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/so_cardView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:paddingRight="10dp"
            android:textColor="@color/SoColor"/>

    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

**FirebaseRecyclerView Adapter class:**

```
FirebaseRecyclerAdapter <post, postViewHolder> firebaseRecyclerAdapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<post, postViewHolder>(

                post.class,
                R.layout.post_row_recycle_home,
                postViewHolder.class,
                mDatabaseReference
        ) {
            @Override
            protected void populateViewHolder(postViewHolder viewHolder, post model, int position) {
                viewHolder.setTi(model.getTi());
                viewHolder.setde(model.getDe());
            }
        };
        mrecyclerView.setAdapter(firebaseRecyclerAdapter);


    }
    public static class postViewHolder extends RecyclerViewPager.ViewHolder{

        View mView;

        public postViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            mView = itemView;
        }

        public void setTi(String ti){
            TextView post_ti = (TextView)mView.findViewById(R.id.ti_cardView);
            post_ti.setText(ti);
        }

        public void setde(String de){
            TextView post_de = (TextView)mView.findViewById(R.id.de_cardView);
            post_de.setText(de);
        }
```

Comment: You have put both imageview and videoview in the same layout. So every item in your listview contains both items. The best solution I can suggest you is to hide one of them pragmatically one of them at a time and show the other according to your data.

Comment: @ZohaibHassan can it be achieved with FirebaseRecyclerAdapter?

Comment: Yes it can be achieved with RecyclerView. But I am not sure about FirebaseRecyclerAdapter.

Answer (score 0):

> set visibility of both gone at first and then depending on its video url or image url. manipulate Visibility of each view
>
> ```html
> <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
> <android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
>     xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
>     xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
>     android:id="@+id/CardView"
>     android:layout_width="match_parent"
>     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>     card_view:cardCornerRadius="10dp">
>
>     <LinearLayout
>         android:layout_width="match_parent"
>         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>         android:orientation="vertical">
>
>        <com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerView
>              android:visibility="gone"
>             android:id="@+id/youtube"
>             android:layout_width="match_parent"
>             android:layout_height="200dp"/>
>
>         <ImageView
>            android:visibility="gone"
>             android:id="@+id/po_image"
>             android:layout_width="match_parent"
>             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>             android:adjustViewBounds="true"
>             android:scaleType="centerCrop" />
>
>         <TextView
>             android:id="@+id/ti_cardView"
>             android:layout_width="match_parent"
>             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>             android:padding="10dp"
>             android:textSize="18sp"
>             android:textStyle="bold"/>
>
>         <TextView
>             android:id="@+id/de_cardView"
>             android:layout_width="match_parent"
>             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>             android:paddingLeft="10dp"
>             android:paddingRight="10dp" />
>
>         <TextView
>             android:id="@+id/so_cardView"
>             android:layout_width="match_parent"
>             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>             android:paddingLeft="10dp"
>             android:paddingRight="10dp"
>             android:textColor="@color/SoColor"/>
>
>     </LinearLayout>
>
> </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
> ```

Comment: When i set visibility to gone and add a video id for youtube my application shows an error of youtube player crash.

Comment: what is crash log?

Comment: I will surely post it soon in my question sir

Comment: dont call me sir bro .. we are here to help each other

Comment: There is no error log bro, but youtube player is also not visible if there is a video id in it and it shows in dialog the error of youtube has stopped.

Answer (score 0):

As you are using RecyclerView, don't put the VideoPlayer and the ImageView in the same xml layout, you can create two different layouts and use the `getItemViewType()` to choose the right layout to inflate.

The questions on how to use differente layouts on the same RecyclerView has been answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26245463/7469136)

Sample code:

```
        image_item_layout.xml

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/CardView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        card_view:cardCornerRadius="10dp">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <ImageView
               android:visibility="gone"
                android:id="@+id/po_image"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop" />

           <...>

        </LinearLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

video_item_layout.xml

<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/CardView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    card_view:cardCornerRadius="10dp">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

       <com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerView
             android:visibility="gone"
            android:id="@+id/youtube"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="

        <...>

    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

On the ImageOrVideoAdapter.java you can use something like:

```
public class ImageOrVideoAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {

    private List<ImageOrVideoItem> dataSource;

    private final int VIDEO_VIEW = 0;
    private final int IMAGE_VIEW = 1;

    class VideoItemViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        // Do your stuff with the video here

        public VideoItemViewHolder(View itemView) {
        }
    }

    class ImageItemViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        // Do your stuff with the image here
        public ImageItemViewHolder(View itemView) {
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        return dataSource.get(position).isVideoItem() ? VIDEO_VIEW : IMAGE_VIEW;
    }

    @Override
    public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
        switch (viewType) {
            case VIDEO_VIEW:
                return new VideoItemViewHolder(inflater.inflate(R.layout.video_item_layout, parent, false));
            case IMAGE_VIEW:
                return new ImageItemViewHolder(inflater.inflate(R.layout.image_item_layout, parent, false));
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
        switch (holder.getItemViewType()) {
            case VIDEO_VIEW:
                VideoItemViewHolder viewHolder0 = (VideoItemViewHolder) holder;
                break;

            case IMAGE_VIEW:
                ImageItemViewHolder viewHolder2 = (ImageItemViewHolder) holder;
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

There are many posts all around StackOverflow about handling diferent layouts for the same RecyclerView, look around, you will find them.

---

**EDIT**

Take a look on this example using FireBase and see if it can adapted to fit your needs: [Here](https://medium.com/chanse-games-developers/firebaserecycleradapter-with-multiple-viewtype-31b622d9ef5a)

Comment: sir I am using Firebase as a database and using FirebaseRecyclerAdapter in it, can i use it with it.

Comment: Yes you can. I edited the answer with a link about using it with FireBase

Comment: Sir i have already checked this post, but isnt there a firebase update in which we use itemViewType() and it functions the same?